# Returning function from compiled string in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a function from a string and return it from another Python function. Example below

```
def compile_functions() -> t.Callable:
    code = """def f():\n\treturn 1"""
    compiled = compile(code, "<string>", "exec")
    exec(code)
    return f
```

However this produces `NameError: name 'f' is not defined`. What am I missing?

Comment: For a good example of how you can use dynamic compilation, check out how the [`dataclasses` module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/dataclasses.py#L413) does it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `exec()` is running your code in different scope than the one your `compile_functions()` method is defined in. As per `exec()`'s [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec):

> If only `globals` is provided, it must be a dictionary, which will be used for both the global and the local namespace. If `globals` and `locals` are given, they are used for the global and local namespace, respectively. If provided, `locals` can be any mapping object. Remember that at module level, `globals` and `locals` are the same dictionary. If exec gets two separate objects as `globals` and `locals`, the code will be executed as if it were embedded in a class definition.

so as a solution, you need to stuff `exec()` with empty `{}` for its `globals` argument. Updated code, which would now return expected `1`:

```py
def compile_functions() -> t.Callable:
    code = """def f():\n\treturn 1"""
    compiled = compile(code, "<string>", "exec")
    namespace = {}
    exec(compiled, namespace)
    return namespace['f']
```